# What is the replacement for the now removed Firefox's Developer Toolbar (GCLI)?

Tags: firefox, web-developer-toolbar

Forenote: This post is referring to the [developer toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI), also known as GCLI, opened by pressing <kbd>Shift + F2</kbd>. It is not referring to the developer tools, opened by <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + I</kbd>

The developer toolbar has been removed from Firefox since 18th May 2018 in nightly builds. But I wasn't able to find any replacement for the features that it had.

For example, previously, you could view the print only media (sending to printer) by typing `media emulate print` in the GCLI. However, there appears to be nothing now which allows us to view print in Firefox.

Is there an equally featured replacement? Or have we simply lost this feature?

Comment: For `media emulate print`, It seems [they intended](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zrdm-V9WAQ11I5oxfqCt_M0VvF24NEWnT93VrzPRglU/edit#gid=578856175) to put it either in ResponsiveDesignMode or in Inspector, but indeed, I can't find it in the ["Depends on"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1429421) bugs. You might want to remind them from this [bug-report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1429421)? For others, many have been removed (as shown in the first link table) and some are being processed (as shown in the "Depends on" list from the bug-report)